# Webpack compile only if changed

Tags: webpack

My web project is primarily Python, but I am using Webpack to compile and compress my Javascript, and it is working quite nicely.

The compilation takes a good little bit, but that's both expected and acceptable. However, when I run my tests locally, the only way that I've found to ensure that I have the latest Javascript is to compile it.

This becomes a big problem the more I desire to test. Most of the time the code I'm packing hasn't changed, because that's not what I'm working on. So between test runs webpack's output won't change. I still have to incur the cost of packing, because I can't guarantee that it hasn't changed.

Is there a way for webpack to see if the source files have changed since the last pack was created, and only pack if the pack that already exists isn't from the same source files?

Comment: Why hasn't the code under test changed? Are you just writing the tests in isolation (so only the test code changes)? What do you do when you write a failing test - won't you need to refactor the JavaScript test being tested (and thus need to recompile)?

Comment: Most of the code is a Django / Python web project, and that's the code I'm testing. There's a couple test cases that require the packs to _exist_, but none that require them to be _recompiled_ when no Javascript has been changed.

Comment: I see. One approach could be to ```webpack --watch``` when you work on the Django tests. This would cause an initial compile of the JS project, then only if/when the source js changes, would webpack recompile it again.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is a single command that tests the whole project (in this case, the command is `tox`). So then each run, it needs to be able to determine whether it needs to run or not. If I use `--watch`, then a tester must have two terminals open, one for watching, and one for testing, and must run two commands. It works, but it's not the ideal I'm hoping to find.

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy built-in way to do this, but someone wrote a plugin: [only-if-changed-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-if-changed-webpack-plugin). This checks the time on your entry file *and also on all its dependencies* and only rebuilds if something changed.